# <html> and <body> container dont cove the whole page

Tags: html, css

I define html height:100% and build a red border around, the problem is that the html space is not covering the whole page, if I want to cover the whole page I have to use height:150%. I think Im doing something wrong. The red line is html and yellow is body, all is define at height: 100%. I try with 100vh and min height.The problem with all this is that the footer is getting out of the screen because the distance betwween the footer and the  is too big[image: if I low the footer he go our of screen]

```
*,
::before,
::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border:solid 1px;
}
html {
  font-size: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width:100%;
   border:solid red 3px;
 
    height: 100%;
    
}
:root{--color-background:rgb(238,238,238);}

body {
  font-family: 'Baskervville', serif;
  color: black;
  background-color: var(--color-background);
  width:800px;
  height:100%;
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
  align-items:center;
  border:solid yellow 3px;
  
}
img {
  width:100px;height:49px;
  object-fit: contain; 
}
header{
  
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  display:grid;grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px ;
  z-index:100;
  background-color: var(--color-background);
  width:800px;
  }
```

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border:solid 1px;
}
html {
  font-size: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width:100%;height:100%;
}
:root{--color-background:rgb(238,238,238);}

body {
  font-family: 'Baskervville', serif;
  color: black;
  background-color: var(--color-background);
  width:800px;
  height:100%;
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
  align-items:center;
  border:solid yellow 3px;
  
}
img {
  width:100px;height:49px;
  object-fit: contain; 
}
header{
  
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  display:grid;grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px ;
  z-index:100;
  background-color: var(--color-background);
  width:800px;
  }
  #logo{
    display:flex;align-items:center;} 

  #brand{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;font-size: 2rem;}
  nav{
    display:flex;justify-content:flex-end;align-items:center;
    }
  nav ul{
    display:flex;align-items:center;list-style-type: none}
  .nav-link{
  text-decoration: none;color: inherit;
  }
  nav ul li{margin: auto 2vw;}

  form{
    display:flex;flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:center;align-items:center;}
#email,form input{margin:5px;}
#button-email{background-color:rgb(241,196,15);font-weight:bold;font-size:1.1rem;padding:2px;}
i{text-align: center;color:rgb(255,127,39);font-size:2rem;
   }
   #product_features{width:100%;}
.feature{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 1fr;grid-template-rows: 100px;
  align-items:center;
}


main{
  
   height:auto;
    max-height:100%;
    
  width:100%;margin:10px auto;align-items:center;position:relative;top:50px;}
#product-list{display:flex;flex-direction:row;
justify-content:space-evenly;}
.product-box{
  height:250px;
  width:200px;
  margin:10px;
  border:solid 1px black;
  text-align: center;

}
.product-title{
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;font-weight:bold;
  background-color:rgb(221,221,221);
  padding:10px;}
  .product-price{
    font-family: 'sans-serif', serif;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding:5px;}
    .product-description{
padding:30px 2px;
margin:auto;
width:180px;height:70px;


 }
 .product-box button{ 
padding:5px;
margin:2px;
background-color:rgb(241,196,15);

 }
 button, #button-email{cursor:pointer;}

 iframe{display:block;margin:10px auto;}
 footer{
   
   position:relative;
   top:75;
   width:100%;
   margin:1px auto;
    background-color:rgb(221,221,221);text-align:right;
    font-size:0.9rem;font-weight:600;
   
   }
   footer p{font-weight:100;font-size:0.75rem;}

   @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  header {
    grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 75px ;
  z-index:100;
  background-color: var(--color-background);
  width:100%;min-width:500px;}

  body{min-width:500px;width:100%;padding:7px;
  }
  main{top:85;}
  nav{display:block;}
   nav ul{
     
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:center;align-items:center;
    
}
footer{top:105;}
#product-list{display:flex;flex-direction:column;
justify-content:space-evenly;
align-items:center;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="Product Landing Page" />
    <title>Product Landing Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
     <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css"
    />
    
     <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton%7CBaskervville%7CRaleway&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    
      
        <header id="header">

<div id="logo">
<img id="header-img" 
src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f6/Bike-icon.svg/2560px-Bike-icon.svg.png"
            alt="logo of a bike symbol"
            loading="lazy"
            class="image-1"
            width="42.5px"
            height="25px"/>
<h1 id="brand">SuperBike</h1>
</div>


<nav id="nav-bar">
  <ul>
          <li><a class="nav-link bar_button"  href="#Features" accesskey="a">Features</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link bar_button"  href="#How_It_Works" accesskey="b">How It Works</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link bar_button"  href="#Pricing" accesskey="b">Pricing</a></li>
</nav>

        </header>
<main>
        
          
          <form method="post" action='https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit'>
          <h2>We have the better bikes of the market</h2>
      
        <label for="email"><input id="email" name="email" type="email" required placeholder="Enter your email address" /></label>
        <input type="submit" value="GET STARTED" id="button-email"  />
        
        
    </form>
    
    <div id="product_features">
<div class="feature">
  <i class="fa fa-bicycle" ></i>
  <div class="product_features_text">
  <h3>Premium Materials</h3>
  <p>Our bikes are made of high quality materials. We only use top of the line brands.</p></div>
  </div>

<div class="feature"><i class="fa fa-truck" style="font-size:2rem"></i>
<div class="product_features_text">
  <h3>Fast Shipping</h3>
  <p>We make sure you recieve your bike as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p></div></div>

<div class="feature"><i class="fa fa-battery-full" style="font-size:2rem, color:orange"></i>
<div class="product_features_text">
  <h3>Quality Assurance</h3>
  <p>For every purchase you make, we will ensure there are no damages or faults.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
    </div>


    
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nuqxkz_eo8Y" title="Where Should I Ride?" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>


   
<div id="product-list">

<div class="product-box">
  <p class="product-title">picoBike</p>
  <p class="product-price">$500</p>
  <p class="product-description">Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum.
Lorem ipsum dolor.Lorem ipsum.</p>
  <button type="button">SELECT</button>
  </div>
<div class="product-box">
  <p class="product-title">Mega Bike</p>
  <p class="product-price">$700</p>
  <p class="product-description">Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum.
Lorem ipsum dolor.Lorem ipsum.</p>
  <button type="button">SELECT</button>
  </div>
    <div class="product-box">
  <p class="product-title">Giga Bike</p>
  <p class="product-price">$1200</p>
  <p class="product-description">Lorem ipsum.
     Lorem ipsum.
     Lorem ipsum dolor.Lorem ipsum.
     Lorem ipsum.
     </p>
  <button type="button">SELECT</button>
  </div>
</div>


    
   

 <footer>
<a href="#" class="nav-link">Privacy Terms</a>
<a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
<p>Copyright 2016, SuperBike</p>

    </footer>
             


</main>




          
          </body>
          </html>
```

I want to know if is normal that my page is getting cutted

Comment: Please add a code snippet with both HTML and CSS

Comment: I added the whole code, to make it work I made html height:170%. I want to know if that is ok or just a hacky solution

Comment: Instead of %, use viewport sizes vw and vh, when you want to size the elements with respect to the size of the web page. % is used to size elements with respect to their parent element.

Comment: I have added an answer. Please check and let me know if that is what you need, or need more changes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution, at the HTML section in the Css file I define height:100% or 100vh this limited the size of my page whole page to the size of the screen when I delete this I could make my website without any limit, I know is kind of dumb, but I'm rooky. Thanks to everyone.